# Connexion with id address ip - socket

Tags: sockets

I've a problem of connexion with two program in C (like always a client and a server). My problem is when I want to use a specific ip address (my ip address), the connexion between the both didn't work. With this, my program works :   `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);`
But at the moment I change this line by : `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);`
I have a connexion problem so I think the problem is the ip addresse that I use.
I get my Ip address with this command : `/sbin/ifconfig | grep inet` 
So I don't see where is my error.
My client.c :

```
int client_conversation(int port) { 
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  int s,c,r;
  char tampon[SIZE];
  char *ip = "XXX.XXX.X.XX";
  struct hostent *nameHost;

  nameHost = gethostbyname("localhost");
  if(nameHost == NULL) { 
    fprintf(stderr,"%s: host inconnue\n","localhost");
    exit(1);
  }
  s = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if(s == -1) { 
    perror("socket: ");
    exit(1);
  }
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  /**addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);*/
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  memcpy(&(addr.sin_addr.s_addr),nameHost->h_addr_list[0],nameHost->h_length);
  c = connect(s,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
  if(c == -1) { 
    fprintf(stderr,"Connexion impossible\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  if((r = read(s,tampon,SIZE)) > 0) {
    write(1,tampon,r);
  }
  close(s);
  return 0;
}
```

My server.c :

```
int serveur_conversation(int port) { 
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  int s,l,a;
  socklen_t m;
  char *message = "salut";
  char *ip = "XXX.XXX.X.XX";
  s = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if(s == -1) { 
    perror("socket : ");
    exit(1);
  }
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  /**addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);*/
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  if(bind(s,(struct sockaddr *)(&addr),sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind : ");
    close(s);
    exit(1);
  }
  l = listen(s,100);
  if(l == -1) {
    perror("listen :");
    exit(1);
  } 
  do { 
    a = accept(s,(struct sockaddr *)(&addr),&m);
    if(a == -1) {
      perror("accept :");
      exit(1);
    }
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0) {
      if((write(a,message,strlen(message))) == -1) {
    printf("Impossible d'envoyer le message\n");
    exit(1);
      }
      exit(1);
    }
  }while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

If anybody sees the error that I don't see, tell me please!

Comment: So, the question becomes: what IP are you binding to? (is it a 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x or else?) And what is the actual error?

Comment: I'm binding to this IP : 192.168.X.XX and the actual error is : when I try to connect the client to the server, I've a error message (I print "Connexion impossible" when the connexion is ... impossible!) in my client.

Comment: I think it's called connection. Just sayin'

Comment: It's in french "connexion" and I speak the frenglish language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, at the client side you connect to the "localhost"

```
nameHost = gethostbyname("localhost");
...
memcpy(&(addr.sin_addr.s_addr),nameHost->h_addr_list[0],nameHost->h_length);
```

And at the server site you bind to an IP "XXX.XXX.X.XX":

```
char *ip = "XXX.XXX.X.XX"
...
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
```

At the client you use correct form to get the IP of the localhost:

```
nameHost = gethostbyname("localhost");
```

I think you must do the same at the server so both use the same IP, either "localhost" or a fixed const IP like "192.168.1.25". 
That's why you're getting the connection refused at the client.